# Проблема при подключении к веб-морде сервера эмулированного в qemu

Tags: linux, веб-программирование, kernel, arm, qemu

Запускаю qemu с образом этой командой:

```sh
./qemu-system-arm -m 256 -M ast2500-evb -nographic  -drive file=/home/nikita/openbmc/build/tmp/deploy/images/evb-ast2500/obmc-phosphor-image-evb-ast2500-20210118103804.static.mtd,format=raw,if=mtd -net nic -net user,hostfwd=:127.0.0.1:2222-:22,hostfwd=:127.0.0.1:2443-:443,hostname=qemu
```

Далее после запуска и аутентификации в консоли, открываю браузер и пишу:

https://localhost:2443/

Браузер выплевывает:

```
The page isn’t redirecting properly

An error occurred during a connection to localhost:2443.

    This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
```

URl изменяется на: https://localhost:2443/#/login?next=%2F

Comment: ну, разбирайтесь, что там внутри `obmc-phosphor-image-evb-ast2500-20210118103804.static.mtd` накодировали: чего именно от вас ожидает запущенный там внутри http-сервер.

Comment: сделай нормальную сеть на veth